# How to include and use native imagemagick on server in Craft?

Tags: plugin-development, imagick

Craft v2.6.x

I want to write a plugin to grab thumbnails of PDFs.

I have my stand alone php code with imagemagick on server working like this:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$pdf = 'assets/documents/resources/after-release-impact-seafarers.pdf';

$im->setResolution(300,300);
//$im->setCompressionQuality(95);
//$im->scaleImage(200,0);
$im->readimage($pdf . '[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
//$im->resizeImage( 640, 905, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );
//$im->resizeImage( 400, 565, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );
$im->resizeImage( 180, 232, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );

$im->writeImage('1a2w12thumb.jpg');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

However, how can I load imagemagick - which works on the server in my PDF thumbnail plugin class function?
I have tried:

```
    $im = new \Imagick();

    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readimage($pdfAsset . '[0]');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->resizeImage( 640, 905, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );
    $im->writeImage($pdfAsset->writepath.$pdfAsset->filename . '.jpg');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
```

But none of the functions for imagemagick work:
Eg. error i get is Class 'Craft\imagick' not found

Is this a namespace issue with the imagine library? (I sound like I know what I am talking about but I am not sure I do!)

How to include/ use native imagemagick on server in Craft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with [PECL imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), which is the PHP wrapper for the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library, then this should work:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
```

It's not namespaced, so it exists in the global namespace, which is what the `\` does for you.

Comment: Thx Brad.I load the library but the functions don't work. I get a craft namespace error : Class 'Craft\Imagick' not found on
 $im->resizeImage( 640, 905, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1 ); [ or 'imagick::FILTER' etc]

Comment: OK i needed the back slash on the filter too! Eg $im->resizeImage( 640, 905, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1 )

Comment: Ahh, correct.  Probably should have mentioned that. :)